# MySQL Connector/Python Error "Lost connection to MySQL server / Connection reset by peer"

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am new to Python and mySQL and I am trying to get the following Python script running as a CGI on an hosted webserver:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import sys
sys.path.append("PATH TO SIDE PACKAGES DUE TO MISSING ROOT ACCESS")
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

print('Content-type: text/html') # the mime-type header.
print() # header must be separated from body by 1 empty line.


try:
    connection_config_dict = {
        'user': 'MY_USER',
        'password': 'MY_PASSWORD',
        'host': 'rdbms.strato.de',
        'database': 'MY_DATABASE',

    }
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**connection_config_dict)

    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("Your connected to database: ", record)

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error message:

```
Error while connecting to MySQL 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'rdbms.strato.de:3306', 
system error: 104 Connection reset by peer
```

I looked up older threads with the error message and while I could find both separately, I did not find them in this combo, therefore I hope there might be someone having an idea for a solution before I deal with the horrible customer service of my provider again. To me as a newbie it seems like the server declines the connection, even though I am coming from inside the network (running as a CGI on the server).

Some more information about the environment: The Python version is 3.8.1, mySQL server version 5.7, mysql_connector_python version 8.0.23. Since it is a hosted webserver I do not have root access, therefore I installed additional modules with pip --user via ssh and added the path to the script which works fine with other modules like requests. I am also certain that the mySQL login data is correct, since it works flawlessly with a PHP script.

Thanks in advance for helping out!